# Build error on codemagic while ios deployment

Tags: ios, flutter, podfile, codemagic

I am working on a flutter app and I do not have a mac. So I am using codemagic to deploy the app for ios.

While building I received this error-

> Error output from CocoaPods:
> ↳
>
> [!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `11.0` on
> target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a
> platform for this target in your Podfile. See
> `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
>
> Error running pod install
>
> Build failed :| Failed to build for iOS

I cannot make changes in the podfile because I am working on a linux system

Comment: You can make changes to the podfile. It is in your repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a file manually in ios directory called "Podfile" and pasted this content

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  #target 'RunnerTests' do
  #  inherit! :search_paths
  #end
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Notice that I have uncommented the second line (which was not done by default) and also commented these 3 lines

```
  #target 'RunnerTests' do
  #  inherit! :search_paths
  #end
```